# How to get the textarea value from LineControl Editor in MVC Controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using this [jquery plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Responsive-WYSIWYG-Text-Editor-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-LineControl-Editor.html) to create a wysiwyg text editor in my MVC 5 project.

I created a textarea in a view where I want to display the text editor.

The issue is that I can't correctly bind or get the value of text I type into wysiwyg text editor after is posted to controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Pages", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", id = "pageForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div>
    <h4>Page</h4>
    <hr />

    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PagesID)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PagesID)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Body)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Update" name="command" />
}
```

I added the necessary jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function() {
    $("#Body").Editor();                   
  });
</script>
```

Here is the controller code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var page = (from a in context.Pages
                    where a.PagesID == 1
                    select new PageModel
                    { 
                        PagesID = a.PagesID,
                        Body = a.Body
                    }).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(page);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Details(PageModel page, string command)
    {
        string bodyText = page.Body;

        return RedirectToAction("Details/1");
    }
```

viewmodel:

```
public class PageModel
{
    public int PagesID { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Body { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: `@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Body)` creates a textarea with `id="Body"` yet your script is referring to an element with `id="textEditor"`?

Comment: I meant to type:

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Body").Editor();
        });
    </script>

Thanks!  Same issue remains

Comment: Update you question with the correct code :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume as the control formats the contents of the div as html with styling, that it is supposed to be inserted into a database as html. I can't see any documentation on what is supposed to be received server side, so I will assume it would be the html text. This seems dangerous though, as you would then be inserting whatever html a user posts with no sanitizing.

Anyway...You could post the contents using

```
$.post('/Home/Details', { PagesID: 1, Body: $('#Body').html() }, function(response) {
    //On complete
})
```

To be received on controller

```
public ActionResult Details(PageModel page)
{
}
```

And either have ActionResult, JsonResult, etc as return type

**Edit:**

Don't use a textarea. The example shows a div.

```
<div id="Body"></div>
```

I assume this would make a difference between whether you would want to post the html contents or the value of a textarea.

```
$('#Body').html();
```

or

```
$('#Body').val();
```

Comment: Thanks tic - I have to stick to the Html.BeginForm method - I updated this question to reflect how the form looks like.